# What does elastic search Store, and how?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic search is a search engine, according to Wikipedia. This implies it is not a database, and does not store the data it is indexing (but presumably does store its indexes)

There are presumably 2 ways to get data into Es. Log shipping or directly via api.

Let’s say my app wants to write an old fashioned log file entry:

Logger.error(now() + “ something bad happened in module “ + module + “;” + message”

This could either write to a file or put the data directly in es using a rest api.

If it was done via rest api, does es store the entire log message, in which case you dont need to waste disk writing the logs to files for compliance etc. Or does it only index the data, so you need to keep a separate copy?  If you delete or move the original log file, how does es know, and is what it Deos store still usefull?

If you write to a log file, then use log stash or similar to “put the log data in es” does es store the entire log file as well as any indexes?

How does es parse or index arbitrary log files? Does it treat a log line as a single string, or does it require logs to have a specific format such as cvs or Jason?

Does anyone know of a resource with this key info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch does store the data you are indexing.

When you ingest data into elasticsearch, this data is stored in one or more index and then it can be searched. To be able to search something with elasticsearch you need to store the data in elasticsearch, it can not for example search on external files.

In your example, if you have an app sending logs do elasticsearch, it will store the entire message you send and after it is in elasticsearch you don't need the original log anymore.

If you need to parse your documents in different fields you can do it before sending the log to elasticsearch as a json document, use logstash to do this or use an ingest pipeline in elasticsearch.

A good starting point to know more about how it works is the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/elasticsearch-intro.html)